Selecting elementor templates with Wordpress API to create blog posts automatically
I'm working on a project that involves integrating a WordPress site, built with Elementor, with a SharePoint-based list. The idea is that whenever a new item is created in the SharePoint list, a post is automatically generated on the site's blog. To accomplish this, I'm leveraging Microsoft Power Automate, which offers a variety of workflows, including the ability to trigger the WordPress API to create pages automatically.
However, I'm facing some challenges.
Firstly, I'm having trouble selecting a custom template I have saved on my site, created using Elementor. So far, I can only choose from the standard templates (elementor_theme, elementor_canvas, and elementor_header_footer) when using the template function in Power Automate.
Is there a way to select my own custom templatecreated with Elelemtor?
Furthermore, once I can use my custom template, I'm curious if it's possible to direct specific texts to specific text boxes in this template during automation. For example, sending the title of the list item to the title field of the post and the content to the body of the post.
Has anyone encountered these challenges or developed a similar solution? Any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated
I'm trying to create a new endpoind or send a html page, but it's hard.

hi did you figure out how to do the template for post? thanks
